# I have three div's, how to refresh a second div without reloading the complete page?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have three div tags, on click of a link I want to reload the second div tag only instead of loading the complete page, I want to keep the first and third div tag as static and second div tag should be dynamic?

```
  <div class="first">

  <a href="patientLogin/patientVisit_details/<?php echo $data->patient_visit_id;?>"><?php echo $data->hospital_name;?></a>

  </div>


  <div class ="second">
  //content//
  <div>


  <div class ="third">
  //content//
  <div>
```

Comment: give the second div an id , not a class then update via ajax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you should make the difference between your divs by making their IDs unique as  Billy said in the comment. Classes are used to make a common selector for all elements. Create your HTML like below:

```
 <div id="first">
  <a href="patientLogin/patientVisit_details/<?php echo $data->patient_visit_id;?>"><?php echo $data->hospital_name;?></a>
  </div>

  <div id="second">
  //content//
  <div>

  <div id="third">
  //content//
  <div>
```

Now to load data in only a particular div, you can use Ajax request in three ways using jQuery.

```
$('#second').load("load.php");
```

OR

```
$.post('load.php?param=value',function(data){
     $('#second').html(data);
   });
```

OR

```
 $.get('load.php?param=value',function(data){
     $('#second').html(data);
   });
```

OR

```
$.ajax({
   url:"load.php";
   data: yourDataObject,
   success: function(data){
     $('#second').html(data);
   }
});
```

Hope all above will help a little

Answer (score 1):

You can try [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

```
$(".second").load("yourhtml.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

Give id to second div and then try following

```
#secondDivId::after {
 content:"";
}
```

it will refresh the second div.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it's working :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#link").click(function(){
    $(".second").load("abc.html");
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

 <div class="first">

  <a id="link" href="patientLogin/patientVisit_details/<?php echo $data->patient_visit_id;?>"><?php echo $data->hospital_name;?></a>

  </div>


  <div class ="second">
  //content//
  <div>


  <div class ="third">
  //content//
  <div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here, abc.html is the file where your content exist that you want to display in `<div class="second">...</div>` on click the link.

Comment: im using codeigniter framework, if it is the case then how could i load my view page?

Comment: @madhu, I am taking about basic logic to change the second div dynamically. without changing the other elements of the page.

Comment: thank you for your answer. it was indeed helped me knowing the logic.

Comment: @madhu, If you think this answer is helpful for you. Please tick on it. So that others can also find the good solution.